# Continuity of a bivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + y^4}, & \text{ }\text{(x,y)}  \neq (0,0) \\
0, & \text{ }\text{(x,y)}  =  (0,0)
\end{cases} .$$

Show that $\frac{df}{dx} (0,0)$ exists, and $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Write down the limit defining the partial derivative. What do you get?  Compute the limit of $f$ along the path $x=y$ and compare with that value of $f(0,0)$.  What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For existence of the partial derivative:

By definition, $f_x(0,0)$ is the limit
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{f(h,0)-f(0,0)\over h }.
$$
Show that  this limit exists for your particular function.

For continuity:

Note that,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x,x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{x^4\over2x^4}={1\over2}.
$$
Keeping this in mind and the fact that $f(0,0)=0$, what can you say about the continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$?